# How to run Xcode UI test with a specific target

Tags: swift, environment-variables, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

For design reasons I have to run different targets for different locales. I recently started on the UI testing path with Xcode and I immediately run into trouble.

I followed the WWDC session and added a UI test target that runs off of one of the targets.

UI recording works fine.

The thing is my app depends on the AppLocale in the AppDelegate to load some backend stuff. So when I run the UI tests my AppLocale returns the default 'us', rather that the expected 'it'.

I of course tried to manually edit that:

*In the actual test*

```
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launchArguments.append("-AppleLanguages")
        app.launchArguments.append("(it)")
        app.launchArguments.append("-AppleLocale")
        app.launchArguments.append("it_IT")
```

but it seem that these arguments do not reach my app, as the arguments array is empty:

*In AppDelegate, -applicationDidLaunchWithOptions*

```
var arguments = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments
print("arguments: \(arguments)")
print(appID)
```

*Console output while UI testing*

```
arguments: []
iphone1.us.prod
```

My targets are configured as to run with the correct locale and language and when debugging, they exactly that. When I run them that way the output in the console is as I would expect:

*Console output while debugging*

```
arguments: ["-AppleLocale", "it_IT", "-AppleLanguages", "(it)", "-NSTreatUnknownArgumentsAsOpen", "NO", "-ApplePersistenceIgnoreState", "YES"]
iphone1.it.prod
```

I tried to make sure the UI test target gets to the actual app. What I did was to edit the **Build Settings** for the test target and make sure the **Linking** and **Testing** sections point to the correct target.

That way I got to load the correct target and can confirm that all the arguments are correctly setup. But what happens now is that the environment starts the test and never finishes it.

*Console output while UI testing with the Linking and Testing for the test target edited*

```
Test Case MyTestCase started.
    t =     0.00s     Start Test
    t =     0.00s     Set Up
```

This is what I get in the console and that's it. It stops there and nothing more happens after that.

So my question is what am I missing? Is there a way to be very specific in what target are the UI tests running?

I will be happy to provide any additional information you require in order to help me sort this one out!

Answer (score 0):

I work with a slightly different code and for me it works. I set the launchArguments with an array parameter with all needed arguments.

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
    continueAfterFailure = false
    app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launchArguments = [
        "-inUITest",
        "-AppleLanguages",
        "(de)",
        "-AppleLocale",
        "de_DE"
    ]
```